# Gold - golden, Holz - hölzern - Bildung des "Stoffadjektivs"

Tags: vocabulary

Nach welchen Regeln wird das Stoffadjektiv gebildet.

> golden, bronzen, basalten
>
> hölzern, eisern, tönern

Ich habe das Gefühl von jedem Nomen ein Stoffadjektiv bilden zu können.

> tischern (nicht: Tischen), watten (nicht: wattern), ozonen (nicht: ozonern), bären (nicht: bärern), fischern (nicht: fischen)

Diese Beispiele sind natürlich absurd aber für mich funktioniert immer nur eine Version.

- Welche Prinzipien sind hier am Werke?

Comment: Möglicherweise sollte man zum Herausfinden ältere Formen der adjektive wählen. Statt `golden` das ältere `gülden`. Vergrößere mal noch die bekannte Beispielmenge, vielleicht erkennt man dann was: `irden`, `steinern`, `metallen`, `wollen`, …

Comment: Wieso nicht tischig, wattig, ozonig/ozon, bärig, fischig?

Comment: @userunknown Emanuel meint Adjektive, die die stoffliche Zusammensetzung beschreiben, keine Ähnlichkeit. Die abgeleiteten Adjektive auf `-ig` beschreiben aber Ähnlichkeiten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die einfachen:

- Endet ein Wort in *-r*, wird nur noch ein *-n* angehängt (theoretisch *-en*, aber das *e* wird üblicherweise fallen gelassen):

  - Leder -> ledern
  - Fasern -> fasern
  - Marmor -> marmorn
  - Silber -> silbern
  - Wasser -> Wassern
  - Papier -> papier(e)n
- Endet ein Wort in *-e*, wird nur noch ein *-n* angehängt (theoretisch *-en*, aber das *e* wird fallen gelassen):

  - Fichte -> fichten
  - Seide -> seiden
  - Watte -> watten
  - Wolle -> wollen
- Generell, wenn ein Wort in Vokal endet, wird *-en* angehängt und in aller Regel gekürzt:

  - Talmi -> talmin
  - Soda -> sodan
  - Kakao -> kakaoen
  - Balsa -> balsan
- Endet ein Wort in *-en*, wird dieses durch *-ern* ersetzt:

  - Eisen -> eisern
  - Knochen -> knöchern

Jetzt die schwierigen:

- Endet ein Wort in *-ei* oder *-ein*, wird *-ern* angehängt:

  - Bein -> beinern
  - Stein -> steinern
  - Schwein -> schweinern
  - Blei -> bleiern
- Endet ein Wort in *-t* oder einem T-Sound, wird *-en* angehängt:

  - Gold -> golden
  - Kobalt -> Kobalten
  - Bismut -> bismuten
  - Smaragd -> smaragden
  - Sulfat -> sulfanten
  - Zinkbromid -> zinkbromiden
  - Sand -> sanden
  - Ausname:

    - Brett -> brettern
- Endet ein Wort in *-p(s)* oder *-k(s)* oder entsprechenden Sound, kommen beide Endung vor. Abgeleitet von dem, was ich gefunden habe, würde ich folgende Regel aufstellen:

  - Einsilbig mit kurzem Vokal vor dem Konsonant -> *-ern*:

    - Brett -> brettern
    - Speckern -> speckern
    - Wachs -> wachsern
    - Lachs -> lachsern
    - Gips -> gipsern
  - Einsilbig aber langer Vokal vor dem Konsonant -> *-en*

    - Teak -> teaken
  - Steht ein Konsonant davor -> *en*:

    - Zink -> zinken
    - Kork -> korken
    - Kalk -> kalken
- Endet ein Wort in *-s* oder *-z*, wird *-ern* angehängt:

  - Glas -> gläsern
  - Holz -> hölzern
  - Pelz -> pelzern
- Endet ein Wort in *-h*, welches nach Anhängen des Suffixes betont wird, wird *-ern* angehängt:

  - Stroh -> strohern
- Endet ein Wort in *-sch* oder *-ch*, gibt es keine Eindeutigkeit:

  - Blech -> blechern
  - Zwilch -> zwilchen
  - Plüsch -> plüschen
- Endet ein Wort in *-f*, *-ng*, *-n*, *-m* oder *-l*, wird *-(e)n* angehängt:

  - Messing -> messingen
  - Hanf -> hanfen
  - Schilf -> schilfen
  - Metall -> metallen
  - Magnesium -> magnesiumen
  - Wolfram -> wolframen
  - Nickel -> nickeln
  - Lehm -> lehmen
  - Ausname:

    - Zinn -> zinnern; aber: Zinne -> zinnen

Wie immer gilt: Ausnahmen bestätigen die Regel.

Comment: Wer weitere Beispiele hat, Fehler findet, Gegenbeispiele(Ausnahmen) kennt, eine fehlende Regel ausfindig macht -> Bitte kommentieren

Comment: Ich glaub ich hab die Regel für "-sch" und "-ch". Blech und Tisch haben kein Betonung auf dem Vokal. Beim Hinzufügen eines Suffixes legt man eine leichte Betonung auf das "(s)ch": Blechhhhern, Tischhhhern. Bei Plüsch, Milch, Zwilch ist der Vokal leicht länger, und man hat ggf die Möglichkeit, die Betonung auf den Konsonanten zu legen: Plüüüschen, Millllchen, Zwilllchen --- Bin mir aber nicht sicher, ob das nur zufällig diese Beispiele betrifft... Will think about it a little more.

Comment: @Em1... klingt sehr sehr überzeugend! Vielleicht hast du da wirklich einen Trend entdeckt :)

Answer (score -2):

Tisch und tischern ist meiner Meinung nach kein stoffliches Ding wie Gold und golden, weil ein Tisch kein Ding aus einer Sache ist wie Gold. Auch nicht, wenn der ganze Tisch aus Holz ist.

Ich denke, mit tischern, wattern und so weiter verwirrt man nur. Eine goldene Münze ist ok, ein tischernes Möbel ist albern.

Comment: Das ist jedoch keine Antwort auf die Frage, welche Bildungsregeln für diese Adjektive gelten. @Emanuel erwähnt extra, dass die genannten Beispiele wie "tischern" absurd sind.

Comment: Das ist mir klar. Trotzdem klingt "tischern" für mich richtig und "tischen" nicht. Und mich interessiert, welche Prinzipien dahinterstecken, die dann auch absurde Bildungen steuern.